# suspend(agent) is not working in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a SERVICE block which i want to stop working for two hours when 10th agent enter the service.
So I used agent **suspend and resume** function for that. The image of implementation is given below.

[image]

**MyDynamicEvent** Properties section:
[image]

Now when i run the model and 10th agent enter the SERVICE, `traceln("reparing")` gets print on console but **MyDynamicEvent** does not work which means SERVICE block does not stop working and agents keep passing the SERVICE block. It suppose to stop for 2 hours when 10th agent enters the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understand Dynamic Events wrong. In your code, you are creating the DE when the 10th agent enters, but you *schedule* it to start 2 hrs later. So it will trigger, but 2 hrs after the 10th agent arrived.

So the problem does not lie with the DE, but with the `self.suspend()`, imo

Comment: What is happening is when if statement runs,  DE triger and only one agent get suspended the new agents that come pass through the service. 
I can stop all the new coming agents using Wait block but that will not a good approach. i have to suspend all the coming agents, but how?

Comment: Your suspend() refers only to the single 10th agent that passes through your service. Your count then resets, letting all other agents free to continue until the next 10th agent. You can create a function that iterates through all relevant agents and suspend()s them, or you can use the Downtime block to model maintenance, though I don't know enough about your model to elaborate further.